# Does ubuntu 16+ (specifically for ARM) have HDMI drivers by default?

Tags: drivers, hdmi, asus, raspberrypi, arm

I just tried to use the ARM-compatible version of ubuntu (the v16 LTS) on an ARM-based single-board computer that has built-in HDMI hardware. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work, because all I see on the screen is the backlight turn on, no actual display. Yet on the same system/install the built-in MIPI DSI output worked without a problem. I figure the HDMI output ought to be enabled by default, but I can't seem to confirm that. Basically **I'm not sure if the problem is with ubuntu, or with the screen**.

I've tried it on two different SBCs, a Raspberry Pi 3 B, and an Asus Tinker Board, with the exact same results. Do I need to do any additional configuration of ubuntu before using the HDMI output, or should I be looking into a new screen?

*Incidentally, I've also tried Lubuntu, TinkerOS (on the Asus board), and even RetroPie, all with the same results, but ubuntu 16 or 17 is what I really want to use.

Answer (score 1):

I have used Ubuntu 16.04 on my Odroid XU4 with a perfect HDMI support. I have also used the same Ubuntu version on Wandboard Quad, also with HDMI screens. I think it could be a problem with your screen. Here are the images for download:

[Odroid Ubuntu 16.04 Images](https://wiki.odroid.com/odroid-xu4/os_images/linux/ubuntu/ubuntu)

[WandBoard Ubuntu 16.04 Images](https://www.wandboard.org/downloads/)

You could also try with the UDOO SBPC:

[UDOO Downloads, Ubuntu 12.04](https://www.udoo.org/downloads/)

Comment: I'll look into those, thanks. I'm also leaning towards a screen problem, but I don't know how to verify that without knowing for sure that the OS *should* be supporting it.